# How to exclude parameters when caching function calls with DiskCache and memoize?

Tags: python, diskcache

I am using Python's DiskCache and the memoize decorator to cache function calls to a database of static data.

```py
from diskcache import Cache
cache = Cache("database_cache)

@cache.memoize()
def fetch_document(row_id: int, user: str, password: str):
    ...
```

I don't want the user and password be part of the cache key.

How can I exclude parameters from the key generation?

Comment: base on documentation for [memoize](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html#diskcache.FanoutCache.memoize) you can't exclude parameters. You will have to write own decorator. Or inside `fetch_document` use `cache[row_id] = result` with `if/else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for [memoize](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html#diskcache.FanoutCache.memoize) doesn't show option to exclude parameters.

You may try to write own decorator - using [source code](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-diskcache/blob/master/diskcache/recipes.py#L398).

Or use `cache` on your own inside `fetch_document` - something like this

```
def fetch_document(row_id: int, user: str, password: str):
    if row_id in cache:
         return cache[row_id]

    # ... code ...
              
    # result = ...

    cache[row_id] = result

    return result
```

---

**EDIT:**

OR create cached version of your function - like this

```
def cached_fetch_document(row_id: int, user: str, password: str):
    if row_id in cache:
         return cache[row_id]

    result = fetch_document(row_id: int, user: str, password: str)

    cache[row_id] = result

    return result
```

and later you can decide if you want to use `cached_fetch_document` in place of `fetch_document`

Comment: I didn't know I could talk to the cache directly. I thought I have to use a decorator. This makes life much easier. I can treat `cache` like a dictionary that is stored in a file. It seems that parameters like `expire` that I usually pass to the decorator `@cache.memoize` can be set with `cach.set(expire)`

Answer (score 2):

After version 5.3.0, memoize can use the ignore argument to ignore the positional arguments