# Ignoring a parameter while caching asyncio functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, caching, aiohttp

So in [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/http_request_lifecycle.html#how-to-use-the-clientsession) it is suggested to reuse the ClientSession to avoid overhead.

So say I have something like this:

```py
async def get_id_from_url(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return (await response.json())['id'] if response.ok else ''


async def get_ids(urls: List[str]):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ids = await asyncio.gather(*[get_id_from_url(session, url) for url in urls])
        print(ids)
```

I would like to cache the `get_id_from_url` function, I have looked at many questions/packages relating to caching async functions: [aiocache](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiocache)
and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723144/4126652).

But there is one problem, I don't want the caching to depend on the session parameter, I only want it to depend on the url parameter.

How can I do that?

Comment: instead of using decorator `@cached` you can use `cache` inside function and keep result using only url - `cache.set(url, result)` and `if url in cache: return cache.get(url)`

Comment: Few days ago there was similar question [How to exclude parameters when caching function calls with DiskCache and memoize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439103/how-to-exclude-parameters-when-caching-function-calls-with-diskcache-and-memoize/67441205#67441205) and you can see example for [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research I found the `cachetools` library and this [pull request](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/pull/112).

I just took the solution from there: this is an implementation of asyncio support for `cachetools`. And `cachetools` already allows you to pass a key parameter that allows you to chose which parameters of the function will be involved in the hashing.

```py
import functools
import inspect
import logging

from cachetools.keys import hashkey

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class NullContext(object):
    """A class for noop context managers."""

    def __enter__(self):
        """Return ``self`` upon entering the runtime context."""
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Raise any exception triggered within the runtime context."""

    async def __aenter__(self):
        """Return ``self`` upon entering the runtime context."""
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Raise any exception triggered within the runtime context."""


def aiocached(cache, key=hashkey, lock=None):
    """Decorator to wrap a function or a coroutine with a memoizing callable.

    When ``lock`` is provided for a standard function, it's expected to
    implement ``__enter__`` and ``__exit__`` that will be used to lock
    the cache when it gets updated. If it wraps a coroutine, ``lock``
    must implement ``__aenter__`` and ``__aexit__``.
    """
    lock = lock or NullContext()

    def decorator(func):
        if not inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            raise RuntimeError('Use aiocached only with async functions')

        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            fk = key(*args, **kwargs)
            async with lock:
                fval = cache.get(fk)
            # cache hit
            if fval is not None:
                return fval
            # cache miss
            fval = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                async with lock:
                    cache[fk] = fval
            except ValueError:
                logger.debug('Failed to cache {0}'.format(fval))
            return fval
        return functools.wraps(func)(wrapper)
    return decorator
```

Now you can use the `aiocached` decorator just like `cached`